# how to select unique keywords from a comma separated tags

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

I want to retrieve some tags from my database, they are in the form:

```
topic_id       tags
   1        `tag1,tag2,tag3`
   2        `tag1,tag4,tag5`
   3        `tag2,tag4,tag5`
   4        `tag6,tag7,tag2`
```

I want to have something like this:

```
tag1 tag2 tag3 tag4 tag5 tag6 tag7
```

i.e all unique tags

So that I can wrap each tag in a link in order to group news articles that has such specific tags.

This following query I've written so far is not working:

```
$tags = mysql_query("SELECT tags, topic_id
                       FROM forum_topics
                       WHERE topic_id > 0")  or die (mysql_error());
                    while($tag = mysql_fetch_assoc($tags)){   
                    $split_tags  = "$tag";
                    $pieces = explode(",", $split_tags);
                    echo $pieces ;
```

When I did  `print_r($pieces);`

I got `Array ( [0] => Array ) Array ( [0] => Array ) Array ( [0] => Array ) Array ( [0] => Array )`

Which was not what I was looking for.

As it is now my table structure looks like this `topic_id , topic_head, topic_body, topic_tag, topic_date, topic_owner` .. How can I further make the topic_tag normal.

Comment: Is this a table that you constructed? If so, it's clearly not normalized. A normalized table would have a 1-to-1 mapping between the topic_id and the tags. You could then simply do a `select distinct tags from forum_topics` query to get what you want.

Comment: Also, do not use the `mysql_*` functions in your code. These functions are no longer maintained and are [being deprecated](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead, you should use either [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo). Don't know which to use? [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) should help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you normalize your database design, then you could get all the distinct tags very easy by

```
SELECT DISTINCT tags FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id > 0
```

But now, with your database structure, you can't do this, you have to get all the tags and use  `array_unique` on them.

```
$tags = array();
$rows = mysql_query("SELECT tags FROM forum_topics WHERE topic_id > 0")  or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($rows)){   
  $tags = array_merge($tags, explode(',' $row['tags']));
}
$tags = array_unique($tags);
print_r($tags);
```

**But even you could do this, normalize your database design is the best choice.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As it is now my table structure looks like this      

`topic_id , topic_head, topic_body, topic_tag, topic_date, topic_owner` .. How can I further make the topic_tag normal.

Comment: @DotOyes Create another table `topic_tags` to manage the relation of topics and tags.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$tags = "";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($tags)) {   
    $tags .= $row["tags"] . ",";
}

$tags = rtrim($tags, ",");
$pieces = explode(",", $tags);

print_r($pieces); // all of them

$pieces = array_unique($pieces);

print_r($pieces); // distinct
```

...and as [Jonah Bishop already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12344590/how-to-select-unique-keywords-from-a-comma-separated-tags#comment16574052_12344590), please avoid `mysql_*` functions.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct tags from forum_topics;
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this will result in what the OP wants. His table isn't normalized, so you'll (potentially) get back as many results as there are entries.

Comment: Ahh, well that complicates things. (And sorry I didn't see your comment).